# como puedo generar consulta de datos duplicados cuando 2 columnas son iguales?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito ayuda para poder generar una consulta en el cual se repiten los datos en 2 columnas y cuando eso pase que me muestre el primero en este caso las columnas repetidas son estudio y tipo, he intentado con tablas de expresión común haciendo una consulta agrupada solo con estudio y tipo pero cuando realizo el inner join consigo el mismo resultado porque cuando encuentra nuevamente el estudio y el tipo lo obtiene de la tabla principal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Benja: Elabora un escenario con los scripts de creación de tablas y datos de ejemplo, para poder aportar una ayuda adecuada. [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acá hago un JOIN entre la tabla y una subquery que incluye el mínimo "id" para cada grupo "estudio, tipo", además calculo el campo duplicado con 1 o 0 dependiendo la cantidad de registros agrupados:

```
SELECT t.*, aux.duplicado
FROM nombre_tabla AS t
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT MIN(id) AS id, estudio, tipo, CASE WHEN count(*) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS duplicado
   FROM nombre_tabla AS t
   GROUP BY estudio, tipo) AS aux ON t.id = aux.id;
```

Esta query es mas simple pero no incluye la fecha:

```
SELECT MIN(id) AS id, estudio, tipo, CASE WHEN count(*) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS duplicado
FROM nombre_tabla AS t
GROUP BY estudio, tipo;
```